# tr-ng-grid not respecting order-by

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I am using this angularjs module for a table: http://moonstorm.github.io/trNgGrid/release/index.html

I am displaying my data like this:

```
<table tr-ng-grid="" items="logs"  page-items="100" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th field-name="id"         display-name="id"           enable-filtering="false"></th>
            <th field-name="user"       display-name="User"         enable-filtering="false"></th>
            <th field-name="action"     display-name="Action"       enable-filtering="false"></th>
            <th field-name="additional" display-name="Additional"   enable-filtering="false"></th>
            <th field-name="time"       display-name="Time"         enable-filtering="false"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The data is coming from an `$http` call and when I do a console.log() on that data, it is in the correct order. The dispay on the table was not though. You can see below what it looks like

[image]

I added an `order-by` attribute to the `table` element but it doesn't seem to have any effect:

`<table tr-ng-grid="" items="logs" order-by="time" page-items="100" class="table table-striped">`

If I click on the `Time` column to sort, it then sorts it in the correct order. Sorting by `id` doesn't work because it seems to do this:

1,
10,
11,
12,
...
18,
19,
20,
2,
21,
22
etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $http request returns json objects where all fields are strings. Since you feed it directly to your table, your ids are still strings and are ordered as such (1, 10, ...). You need to either preprocess the data and replace your string ids with numbers if you want to order them as numbers, or leverage the trNgGrid column options ; going by the module documentation, I would say a computed field implementing a stringToNumberFormat should do the trick :

```
angular.module(...)
.filter("stringToNumber", function () {
    return function (fieldValueUnused, item) {
        return parseInt(item.id);
    };
});

<th field-name="numberId" display-name="id" display-format="stringToNumber:gridItem">
```

Comment: ah, the numbers are strings...doh! That makes total sense why its ordering it that way. I'll just order by id now then. Thank you

Comment: you know what, even with the id as an int now instead of a string, this still wasn't working. I checked back on the github page and downloaded the latest release and it is working now. On sept. 5th 2014, there was a commit that said `fixed sorting for computed fields`